# Calling save on doc with _id is calling insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document:

```
{ 
  _id: 552bdc73789d083b15e3d6d5,
  username: 'test',
  firstname: 'test',
  lastname: 'test'
}
```

When I call save on that document mongoose is running an insert.

This causes mongo to throw a duplicate key error for the _id field since it already exists.

Any idea why mongoose would be calling insert on a doc that already exists that I retrieved from the db?

EDIT:

Using mongoose 4.0.2 and mongo 2.6.

Here is how I retrieve the doc:

```
var getUserByUsername = function(username, callback) {
  User.findOne({username: username.toLowerCase()}).exec(function(err, user) {
    callback(err, user);
  });
}
```

Then sometime later I call save on that user object:

```
var updateUser = function(user, callback) {
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {  // this is where I see the error
      console.log('Could not update user ' + user.username + ' error ',  err);
    }

    callback(err, user)
  });
}
```

EDIT 2:

How I really retrieve the doc:

```
   Other.findOne({name: name}).populate({path: 'userId', options: {lean: true}}).exec(function(err, token) {
       ...
    }
```

lean populate on userId to populate the user seems to be the problem.

Comment: Sure thing @JohnnyHK,  sorry about leaving out what is probably the most important parts ;)

Comment: That code looks fine. What does the `user.isNew` boolean flag show right before your call to `user.save`? It should be `false` with an existing doc which would lead to an `update` instead of an `insert`.

Comment: isNew returned true.  Which caused to me to look back at the code and realize I lied when I initially told you how I got the doc :(  Thanks for leading my to the problem @JohnnyHK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was lean option in a populate further up the stack.  Thanks @JohnnyHK for showing me the way, I started going up checking isNew until I found the problem.

The original query in question that started the problem:

Other.findOne({name: name}).populate({path: 'userId', options: {lean: true}}).exec(function(err, token) {
       ...
    }

At that point I had a lean user.  That use got passed along and I try to update it at a later time.

At least as of 4.0.2 is a document is lean (not a mongoose object), even if it has an _id save() will not work. I am sure this is as expected and my code has been changed, removing the lean query.